# Number of articles sold by the merchant in a particular week.

Tags: solution-verification, contest-math

> A merchant decides to sell off $100$ articles a week at a selling
> price of $Rs. 150$ each. For each $4 \%$ rise in the selling price he
> sells $3$ less articles a week. If the selling price of each article
> is $Rs. x$, then the expression which will represent the number
> of articles sold by the merchant in that week?

My solution approach :-
In the first week, he sells $100$ items $@$  $Rs. 150$.
In the second week, he sells 97 items $@$ $Rs. 150 \times 1.04 = Rs.156$
In the third week, he sells 94 items $@$ $Rs. 150 \times 1.04 \times1.04  = Rs.162.24$
.
.
.
.
In the $n^{th}$ week, he sells $100-3(n-1) = 103-3n$ items $@$ $Rs. 150 \times 1.04^{n-1}$

Now as per question,  $Rs. 150 \times 1.04^{n-1} = x$
$\Rightarrow 1.04^{n-1}= \frac{x}{150}$
$\Rightarrow 1.04^{n} =\frac{1.04x}{150}$

This is how I proceeded but this seems like that the resulting expression will be very complicated and hence I am not sure if I am going the right way. Please help !

Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: "For each 4 rise in the selling..." sounds for me as a rise of +4 and not a rise of 4%. What is correct? I don't see that the number of sold pieces is decreasing by 3 EVERY WEEK. That's nowhere told in the question

Comment: Probably bad idea to ask mathSE reviewers to guess at the question's intent.  Going forward, with your future mathSE questions, please proofread/edit your question(s) so that they are crystal clear.  That is, please try to make it impossible for anyone to be confused about the problem's constraints, or what you are asking.

Comment: @LegNaiB : I have corrected the question. 
"For each 4% rise in the selling price he sells 3 less articles a week." ==> This means that every week he raises the price by 4% and thus he sells 2 articles less that week from the previous week.

Answer (score 1):

The statement "For each 4% rise in the selling price he sells 3 less articles a week" means: If the merchant changes the selling price to Rs. $150(1.04)$, then he sells $100 -3$ articles; if he changes the price to Rs. $150(1.08)$, then he sells $100 - 6$ articles, and so on.

The general pattern is:

> if the selling price is Rs. $150[1+ k(.04)]$, then he sells $100 -3k$ articles.

You are being asked: If the selling price is $x$, then how many articles will be sold?

To answer this question, set $x$ equal to $150[1+k(.04)]$:
$$ x = 150[1 + k(.04)].$$
Solve this equation for $k$ and substitute the value of $k$ into the expression $100 -3k$. Check your work: When $x=150$, the answer should be $100$. When $x=150(1.04)$, the answer should be $97$, and so on.